# In Java, if I want to make a generic list or binary search tree, do I make Node class extend comparable AND the list or tree class?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am wondering what is the best way to do this?

```
class Node<E>{ }
```

or

```
class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>{ }
```

Then do I need to make the list or bst class extend Comparable as well or can I do the below declaration? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
class BST { private Node<E> root; ... }
```

or

```
class BST<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

I have seen a few variations and would like to know the best one to do. Thanks!!!

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to do? The `Comparable` interface is used to define natural ordering of a certain object. It is then used by `Collections.sort()`, `SortedSet` implementations and `Collections.binarySearch()` to determine object ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is create a new collection. If this is for learning purpose, then you could just define your BST as:

```
class BST<E implements Comparable<E>>{
  private Node root;
  //...
  private class Node{ // instances of Node are bound to the instance of BST
    E elem;
    Node left, right;
  }
}
```

or with a static inner class:

```
class BST<E implements Comparable<E>>{
  private Node<E> root;
  // ...
  private static class Node<X implements Comparable<X>>{
    // similar
  }
}
```

Note that it's good practice to have your `Node` class defined as an inner class and make it either private or with a private constructor. This ensures encapsulation of the implementation.

I want to point out that this is not the approach taken in the SDK. In the library, it's always possible to create a data structure by passing an appropriate `Comparator<E>` so that no natural ordering is required or can be overwritten. If you want to follow this other approach look at the implementation of `TreeSet` or something like that. You can either pass the `Comparator` or the type in the collection will be checked at run time to implement `Comparable`. This has the advantage of being more flexible because you can add to the collection objects for which you cannot change the implementation.

Finally, if you need to implement a collection for a project or work, then don't. The SDK has [plenty of collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and there are also the [Guava collections](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

Answer (score 1):

That's simple.

Have a parent (abstract) class extends Node and implement the Comparable interface like:

```
public class ComparableNode extends Node implemnt Comparable
```

Or, have your Node implement Comparable; then have your generic interface like:

```
private List<ComparableNode> list = new ArrayList<CompraableNode> ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>{

    class Node<E>{
        E value;
    }

}
```